# Download a PDF received from an API call from ERP (weclapp) that is FlateDecoded in Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, erp

I intend to receive a pdf to directly download it from an API call.
What I got back, looks like the following:

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 983>>stream
x��Xo�0Է<ѭC�:�H�]`
����ڍ��֕n"$�
```

What do I need to do to download this? I am working in vuejs/axios as frontend and intend to use express as backend.

I found a similar looking problem here, but without solution: [Download PDF file from api using javascript IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901765/download-pdf-file-from-api-using-javascript-ie9)
I implemented the code, but the resulting pop-up simply stays white

Generally it seems to be a pdf with a FlateDecode-filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this working answer in this thread: https://gist.github.com/javilobo8/097c30a233786be52070986d8cdb1743

It seems like there is a ton of different ways to approach this.

```
  await this.$axios( this.api_url, 
    {method: 'GET', responseType: 'blob', headers: {"AuthenticationToken": this.api_token} }
    ).then(response => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    // works in IE11
    if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob === 'function') {
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(
        response.data,
        `${filename}.pdf`
      );
    } else {
      link.setAttribute('download', `filename.pdf`);
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this utility to download files from an API url.

```
import axios from "axios";

/**
 * utility to download a File from an api url.
 * @param config (optional) config for axios
 */
export default function download(url, config) {
  return axios.get<Blob>(url, {
    ...config,
    responseType: "blob"
  }).then(response => {
    // get filename from content-disposition header
    const contentDisposition = response.headers["content-disposition"];
    const fileName = contentDisposition.match(/\bfilename=([^;]*)/)[1].trim();
    
    //"save" file to hard disk
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
    link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();

    // cleanup
    setTimeout(() => {
      link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
    }, 3000);

    return response;
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this utility! I am still failing to implement it correctly. Do I used it just as one of my functions in my code or did you safe this as an external file, and if so as what? 
I don't recognize this kind of syntax "url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig", also the "headers: Record<string, string>  = ..." throws an error for me. 
I tried to implement the ".then" part but it threw also an error on the "URL.createObjectURL":
"TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided."

Comment: @CB Did you safe this as an external file: yes. I don't recognize this kind of syntax: sry, that's Typescript, didn't think about it. I'll update that. [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).

Comment: Hey so I solved it a bit different than you suggested, but want to let you know how much I appreciate your help!!! Saving the day, have a nice weekend! :)